# How can I make reminders show on the lock screen on iOS 12.01?

Tags: iphone, ios, reminders

I'm on iOS 12.01 with my iPhone 6s and I need to set a reminder and I want it on my lock screen but I can't figure out how to put it there, any help please? It's preetty urgent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reminder automatically appears on the home screen if when you set the reminder, you select *Remind me on a day* in the info menu of that reminder shown as follows:

[image: menu]

Then at the selected time it will appear on the lock screen as shown below:

[image: lock screen]

This is the only way to let a reminder appear on the lock screen.